# ROS Stack/Package to Deb/Ubuntu package mapping?

Tags: rosdep, rosmake, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When rosmake cannot build something because of a missing dependency on some particular package it informs the user of the missing package. If it is a system package, it can produce the apt-get line.

However, if it's a ROS package it's not always clear what deb package that might be part of without doing a bit of research on ros.org

Is there a command line way of determining what deb package must be obtained to get a particular ROS package?

I've tried `apropos` and `apt-cache search` without much success. Is there a better/endorsed way to do this? Am I missing something obvious?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10907/ros-stack/package-to-deb/ubuntu-package-mapping?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Duplicate of http://answers.ros.org/question/1793/which-deb-package-contains-ros-package-x

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-08-15**:
Oops. Thanks.